# problems with data format string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

well, i have this .aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" DataSourceID="test" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
       <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="deuda" 
              HeaderText="deuda" ReadOnly="True"
              SortExpression="deuda" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0}" HtmlEncode="False" />
       </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and its data source has this query:

```
set @lvl = 0;
set @saldo = 0;
WHILE @saldo &lt; (SELECT (80 * (sum(CASE WHEN a1.c11 &lt;&gt; 0 AND DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(FLOAT(10), KDUD.C16), A1.C7) &lt; DATEADD(day, - 90, GETDATE())
 THEN ((a1.C17 / a1.C11) * a1.C20) END)) / 100) 
 FROM kdue a1 
 LEFT JOIN KDMM ON KDMM.C1 = 'U' AND A1.C3 = KDMM.C2 AND A1.C4 = KDMM.C3 AND A1.C5 = KDMM.C4 
 LEFT JOIN KDMS ON A1.C1 = KDMS.C1 
 LEFT JOIN KDUD ON A1.C2 = KDUD.C2 
 LEFT JOIN KDUV ON A1.C18 = KDUV.C2
  WHERE a1.c1 = '02-01') 
  BEGIN SET
   @saldo = @saldo + 
   (SELECT 
   sum(CASE WHEN a1.c11 &lt;&gt; 0 AND DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(FLOAT(10), KDUD.C16), A1.C7) &lt; DATEADD(day, - 90, GETDATE()) THEN ((a1.C17 / a1.C11) * a1.C20) END) AS x
    FROM KDUE A1 
    LEFT JOIN KDMM ON KDMM.C1 = 'U' AND A1.C3 = KDMM.C2 AND A1.C4 = KDMM.C3 AND A1.C5 = KDMM.C4
     LEFT JOIN KDMS ON A1.C1 = KDMS.C1
      LEFT JOIN KDUD ON A1.C2 = KDUD.C2 
      LEFT JOIN KDUV ON A1.C18 = KDUV.C2
       WHERE a1.c1 = '02-01' GROUP BY kdud.c3 ORDER BY x DESC OFFSET @lvl ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY);
        SET @lvl = @lvl + 1 END 
        select replace(cliente,' ','')as cliente,replace(convert(varchar,round(p,0)),'.000000000','')as deuda from
(
SELECT TOP (@lvl) kdud.c3 as cliente, 
        (sum(CASE WHEN a1.c11 &lt;&gt; 0 THEN ((a1.C17 / a1.C11) * a1.C20) END)) AS p 
        FROM KDUE A1 
        LEFT JOIN KDMM ON KDMM.C1 = 'U' AND A1.C3 = KDMM.C2 AND A1.C4 = KDMM.C3 AND A1.C5 = KDMM.C4 
        LEFT JOIN KDMS ON A1.C1 = KDMS.C1 LEFT JOIN KDUD ON A1.C2 = KDUD.C2 
        LEFT JOIN KDUV ON A1.C18 = KDUV.C2 
        WHERE a1.c1 = '02-01' AND DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(FLOAT(10), KDUD.C16), A1.C7) &lt; DATEADD(day, - 90, GETDATE()) 
        GROUP BY kdud.c3 ORDER BY p DESC)as x
```

which returns 2 columns called deuda and cliente, on my asp.net project on visual basic 2013 i tried to add the query to the data source with the wizard but since it adds parameters and they will mess up my query i added the     *asp columns* manually and tried to apply the data format string but it just ignores it... 
data source code:

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="test" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ServIndustrialConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="my query">
```

what can i do to apply the format string correctly to my column?

Comment: The problem is not clear. Did you tried to add the query to the `SqlDataSource` from source view instead of using the wizard? Can you edit your question and append the code of your `SqlDataSource`? not just the sql query.

Comment: sure, let me edit that

Comment: The reason this question is unclear is because there is no question. Please use question format so that people can answer it.

Comment: ah, sorry i just edited that.

Answer (score 0):

well, i noticed that there's nothing wrong on my asp code but on my query i replaced the int values to varchar which caused the data format string to malfunction so i changed my query from this:

```
  replace(convert(varchar,round(p,0)),'.000000000','')as deuda from
```

to this:

```
 replace(int,replace(convert(varchar,round(p,0)),'.000000000',''))as deuda from
```